# Make root view controller disappear in mac OSX swift

Tags: macos, swift

I am trying to move from one controller to another but i want the root view controller to disappear when another view is opened.I only saw popup,model and sheet but the root view controller is still visible in the background.For example in a login page when i click signup the signup page appears and the login page disappears and vice versa.Is there a way to do that in OSX?

Answer (score 1):

At stackoverflow it is common practice to show the code which you have already tried, I would like to advice you to read: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

In regards to your question:

You will need to remove the view that you want to be hidden from its superview.

```
view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Where the "view" is the view you want to be hidden.
You can either pass this view to your function in which you want to hide the view or save it in a variable.

This is if you are using subviews, I am assuming this because as far as I'm aware a new view controller will override the old one.

Answer (score 0):

In OSX, when you refer to "View Controllers" they fall into the responder chain i.e. like Window Controllers.

So basically there's several ways to transition from one view controller (a window?) to another:

1) From one "View Controller" to another within the same "window", you need to rely on:

1. A custom NSWindowController which allows for NSViewController (and its NSView) switching. - HIGHLY not recommended.
2. A custom NSViewController which handles the custom transitions of it's child NSViewControllers. i.e. manually instantiate each child ViewController, and transition from one to the other from the "main" view controller (which is the main one you're viewing0/.
   2 a) Of if you want to use something build in NSTabViewController (which does handle easy transitions) but too isn't recommended for this use.
   3) The only options and definitely not recommended is have separate view controllers) and use segues between them. This could create  multitude of windows.. Depending on the "presentation option" you choose.

   - This is important to note... Click on any one of your Window, view etc.. controllers.. and you'll see a "Presentation" option which you can switch between "single" and "multiple".

     - *Single*: Is where once you instantiate any window / view controller ( or anything in the responder chain), it remains instantiated and doesn't appear multiple times as multiple instances
     - *Multiple*: Is where you have a window, or view (or anything else) that needs to appear multiple times that relies of each of it's instances being separate as opposed to just once i.e. (just one preferences window)... etc...

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to move to the new screen programatically as follows:

Give some Storyboard Id to the second viewController for example `secondView`.

Link the action of the signup button to the First `ViewController` and then add the following code in action method:

```
let secondView = self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("secondView") as? SignUpViewController

self.view.window?.contentViewController = secondView;
```